# GUI - unable to add columns to a ListView

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I want to add columns to a ListView control. You can see what I tried below using `ListView_InsertColumn`, but I'm getting "identifier x is undefined". It should be in `CommCtrl.h`, but I don't know what's wrong. I've seen some people using `CListView_InsertColumn` instead. Not sure what the difference is.

[image]

[image]

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include "resource.h"

#pragma comment(linker, "\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

#include <CommCtrl.h> // LV_COLUMN and ListView_x

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        LVCOLUMNW col;
        col.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVIF_IMAGE;
        col.cx = 40;
        
        ListView_InsertColumn(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST2), 0, &col);

        return TRUE;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return FALSE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    
    HWND hWnd = CreateDialogParamW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDD_MAIN), nullptr, &DialogProc, 0);
    
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBoxW(nullptr, L"Dialog Creation Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_MAIN, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 302
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 169
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_MAIN DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 176
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
CAPTION "Test"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST2,29,44,235,56,LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_MAIN AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0
END

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Comment: Your dialog resource seems to define a list box, not a list view. They are different controls.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, updated it. It's "identifier x is undefined".

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yep. Needs to be a `CONTROL` of type "SysListView32" and also (IIRC) needs the `LVS_REPORT` style.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, and yes, here are all the controls I can use https://i.imgur.com/5GwWOcO.png. I see List Box and List Control only. It just has to look like the one from the image in the question.

Comment: I also had some red squiggles under the `LVCF_` macros and `ListView_InsertColumn` but they went away (eventually) after a few rebuilds. Looks like IntelliSense being dumb.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the control you define in your resource script is a ListBox, not a ListView. For the latter, you'll need to use the generic `CONTROL` statement with a control class of `"SysListView32"` (this can be inserted from the Visual Resource Editor as a "List Control" object, with its "View" property set to "Report"). *Note: Without the `LVS_REPORT` style, you can't add columns to your control.*

Here's a suggested replacement for the dialog resource you have:

```
IDD_MAIN DIALOGEX 0, 0, 309, 176
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
CAPTION "Test"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
//LISTBOX         IDC_LIST2, 29, 44, 235, 56, LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
CONTROL         "", IDC_LIST2, "SysListView32", LVS_REPORT | LVS_SORTASCENDING | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP,
                29, 44, 235, 56
END
```

With *only* that change made, your program will crash/hang during the call to `ListView_InsertColumn`, because you have specified the `LVCF_WIDTH` and `LVCF_IMAGE` flags in the `mask` member of the `LVCOLUMN` structure but have not provided valid data for those flags. I can't just 'invent' an image for you but, with some 'dummy' text values (and an extra column, for good measure), here's a suggestion for some 'fixed' code:

```cpp
    switch (Message) {
        case WM_INITDIALOG: {
            wchar_t c0txt[] = L"abc-0";
            LVCOLUMNW col;
            col.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;// | LVIF_IMAGE;
            col.cx = 40;
            col.pszText = c0txt;
            ListView_InsertColumn(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST2), 0, &col);
            // Add another column...
            wchar_t c1txt[] = L"xyz-1";
            col.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;// | LVIF_IMAGE;
            col.cx = 80;
            col.pszText = c1txt;
            ListView_InsertColumn(GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST2), 1, &col);
            return TRUE;
        }
```

When building your code with *just* the changes outlined above, I get a list view control with two columns:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works as expected! Btw, is it possible to make it responsive, like "Anchor and Dock" properties in C#. Basically to scale right when I resize.

Comment: @nop Not sure - maybe try experimenting with the properties in the "Dynamic Layout" group (and there are many others for style, gridlines, etc.) in the VS Resource Editor.